# How to format QueryString in RouteConfig if your parameter in Action is a Class in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, class, pagination, query-string, routeconfig

I have this piece of code in controller where it accepts a class as a parameter

```
public ActionResult Index(PaginationModel paginationViewModel = null)
{
    //do some logic here
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

And here's what the model looks like

```
public class PaginationModel
{
    protected const int DisplayPageRange = 2;

    //Pagination Related Properties
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }
    public int TotalItems { get; set; }
    public string PageName { get; set; }
    public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }
    public int DefaultItemsPerPage { get; set; }
    public string PagingText { get; set; }

    //Filters
    public string Search { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Star { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set; }
    public string Writer { get; set; }
}
```

I'm calling the action in the view like

```
<a href="/?Category=@genre">@genre</a>
```

Everything seems to work fine but I want to format the URL so it will looks like

```
Movie/Index/Horror/1   //Horror is the category and 1 is the current page number
```

Currently, it's showing

```
Movie/Index?Category=Horror&Page=1
```

I can do it using separate parameters instead of using a class in the action like

```
public ActionResult Index(string category, int pagenum, etc etc)
{

}
```

But is there a way to do this in RouteConfig with class as a parameter?

Edit:

My RouteConfig is

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "MovieSearch",
        url: "Movie/Index/{Category}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Movie", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "AdminSearch",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{key}",
        defaults: new {controller = "Admin", action = "Search", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Movie", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: You need to create a specific route - `url: "Movie/Index/{Category}/{CurrentPage }` and locate it before the default route.

Comment: I did that, its before the Default route but still going to the default route I guess?

Comment: You have not shown what you have done! (how can we guess your mistake)

Comment: It does not have a `{CurrentPage}` paremeter (although not sure if you mean `CurrentPage` or `Page`). And you need to use `@Html.ActionLink()` to generate it (or `Url.Action()` for the `href`attribute if you want to generate the `<a>` tag manually

Comment: Ha! Changing to use ActionLink actually solves the issue. Thanks heaps! Upvoting